# How can I find the problem in the script I wrote in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm making a macro of a game, and I tried a different thing, and now it doesn't seem to be working. I added `if Lf := 1` and `if Rg := 1` which are variables to represent the radio indicator. Here's the code:

```
F9::
toggle :=!Toggle
if (toggle)
{
    SetTimer, Repeat, 100
    Repeat()
}
else
    SetTimer, Repeat, Off
return

Repeat()
{
    Click, 920, 885
    Sleep, 200
    if (Lf := 1)
    {
        Click, 755, 530
        Sleep, 200
        Click, 550, 530
    }
    else if (Rg := 1)
    {
        Click, 1165, 530
        Sleep, 200
        Click, 1370, 530
    }
    Sleep, 200
    Send, {Space Down}
    Sleep, %MilSecOne%
    Sleep, %MilSecOne%
    Send, {Space Up}
    Sleep, 200
}
```

It doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`:=`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetExpression.htm) operator is used to assign a value (which will be the result of an expression) to a variable.
So right now what you're doing, is assigning the number `1` to your variables, and then checking with the if-statement if the value of that variable evaluates to `true`.
(And it always will, non-zero numbers evaluate to `true`)

You're looking for the [`=`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#equal) operator.
In an expression (which is what your `if ( )` -statement is) it compares values, rather than assigns text to a variable, which is what it does in a legacy statement.

So, change
`if (Lf := 1)`
`else if (Rg := 1)`
to
`if (Lf = 1)`
`else if (Rg = 1)`

---

Edit:
I'm also noticing that the variables `Lf` and `Rg` doesn't seem to exist?
At least not in that function's scope.
I hope they're defined as [super-global](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#SuperGlobal) somewhere else.
Otherwise there's no way that code is going to work.

Comment: Well, it's radio in GUI, and I learned that if Radio is toggled, it will become 1.
And what's the difference between x==1, x = 1, x := 1?

Comment: My post and the documentation links in the post explain the difference. `=` is case insensitive comparison, `==` is case sensitive comparison. And yes, a variable associated with a Radio button will hold 0 or 1, but you're missing e.g a [`Gui, Submit`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Submit) to update the variable's contents, and since you're in a function scope, you'd have to specify that you're a variable from outside of the function's scope by using [Global](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Global).